# Converting EPSG 32639 to WGS 84 using Proj.Net gives wrong coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, wgs84, utm

I've used Proj.Net in my c# application to convert from UTM 39N to WGS 84 as below:

```
private const string wkt32639 ="PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 39N\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",51],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32639\"],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH]]";
        public static void ProjectLatLngToXY(double lat, double lng, out double[] xy)
        {
            var gcs_WGS84 = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;

            var cf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            var f = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            var sys32639 = cf.CreateFromWkt(wkt32639);

            var transformTo3857 = f.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(sys32639, gcs_WGS84);
            double[] fromPoint = {lat, lng};
            xy = transformTo3857.MathTransform.Transform(fromPoint);
        }
```

But it gives me the wrong coordinate:
 `WGS84(30.8463279037339, 53.5421539663397) --> UTM( 46.511532454882378, 0.00048291699191924472)`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused which direction you are going in:

Going from 32639 to 4326 (Metres to Degrees):

```
$ gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:32639 -t_srs epsg:4326
30.8463279037339, 53.5421539663397
46.5115324673363 0.000482916992353892 0
```

Going from 4326 to 32639 (Degrees to Metres):

```
$ gdaltransform -t_srs epsg:32639 -s_srs epsg:4326
30.8463279037339, 53.5421539663397
-826917.234636638 6123647.25526846 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you should switch lat and long. I checked in PostGIS and http://spatialreference.org, so the correct coordinate is: 743115.83801353374, 3415337.9391538287

Comment: I just copied your example